# Trouble with Sending and Taking Data from Api, (with Ajax) /jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

Need help to take data from this api;https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/...

```
function findLocation() {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
 $("#data").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " 
+ position.coords.longitude);
});
```

with this code I take GeoLocation of User, Then I shoulduse it and get back appropriate weather conditions of User's Location.

```
$.getJSON( "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/", function( data ) {
var items = [];
$.each( data, function( longitude, lattitude ) {
items.push( "<li id='" + longitude + "'>" + lattitude + "</li>" );
});

$( "<ul/>", {
"temp": "",//Having trouble especially here, how to take data of weather from api
html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "#data" );
});

}
 return false;
}
 $(function() {
$("button").on("click", findLocation);
 });
```

Problem is cannot send longitude and lattitude taken, then take data of weather..

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you:

```
fetch('https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=35&lon=139')
            .then((response) => response.json()).
            .then((data) => /* data is the object u need */)
```